# Reason for a transaction and replace transactions being stuck?

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool

The replaced transaction hash:0xb35ef6f82632d1f132950f71d86e8706236d8659ea6163951adcf63129ce30e1
The original transaction hash:0x9aa8455e38da183f4a01d3e12d02de85048bdb0a4a9fc040140a276159190c20
Today I found a strange transaction in etherscan,this transactions was replaced by a TX with higher max priority.(call replace transaction as TX1)And this transaction taked more than one hour to be confirmed.But I found during this one hour there have many transactions with lower gasprice was confirmed before TX1. Although TX1 has a huge gas limit. Anyone one know the reasons?

Comment: Sometimes validators take longer to include such transactions because they might use the whole block gas limit.